# In LibGDX with Scene2D, how can I continuously walk to the right when a button is pressed?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I have the following piece of code in my `InputAdapter`:

```
...
@Override
public boolean keyDown (int keycode) {
    if (keycode == Keybindings.KEY_RIGHT) this.player.right();
    return super.keyDown(keycode);
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp (int keycode) {
    if (keycode == Keybindings.KEY_RIGHT) this.player.stopMovingRight();
    return super.keyUp(keycode);
}
...
```

And my `PlayerActor` class is responsible for `right()` and `stopMovingRight()`:

```
...
public void right () {
    this.right = true;
    this.setX(this.getX() + 1f);
}

public void stopMovingRight () {
    this.right = false;
}
...
```

Now, when I run the application, my `PlayerActor` moves just 1 unit when I press the `KEY_RIGHT` key (the 'D' key on the keyboard). The problem is that I instead want to *continuously* move the `PlayerActor` while I am pressing down the key.

Situation now:

- Hold down key -> move (just) 1 unit to the right
- Let go of key -> nothing happens

Desired situation:

- Hold down key -> move 1 unit to the right continuously
- Let go of key -> stop moving to the right

I would love to hear your thoughts on this matter, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you encourted here is, that `keyDown()` is called only once, therefore your player id moved only by 1 unit. What you need to do is, create some variable, for example `isMovingRight` and check it every time the game is updated.

Game class:

```
public final void render(float delta) {
...
   player.update();
...
}
```

Player class:

```
public void update() {
   if(isMovingRight) {
      this.setX(this.getX() + 1f);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you dearly! This is exactly what I missed.